I don't understand how this function works, which is reverse() function in implementation of a linked list
Here is code for implementing a singly-linked list:
class LinkedList {
  constructor(value) {
    this.head = {
      value: value,
      next: null,
    };
    this.tail = this.head;
    this.length = 1;
  }

  append(value) {
    const newNode = {
      value: value,
      next: null,
    };
    this.tail.next = newNode;
    this.tail = newNode;
    this.length++;
    return this;
  }

  prepend(value) {
    const newNode = {
      value: value,
      next: null,
    };
    newNode.next = this.head;
    this.head = newNode;
    this.length++;
    return this;
  }

  reverse() {
    if (!this.head.next) {
      return this.head;
    }
    let first = this.head;
    this.tail = this.head;
    let second = first.next;

    while (second) {
      const temp = second.next; //third
      second.next = first;
      first = second;
      second = temp;
    }

    this.head.next = null;
    this.head = first;
    return this.printList();
  }

}

I need someone to help me understand this reverse() function, I tried to understand it a lot of times, and I also tried with ChatGPT haha.
The reverse() function runtime is O(n).

"I need someone to help me in understanding this reverse() function": what exactly is unclear? Have you drawn this out on a piece of paper for a list with 3 or 4 nodes?

Reverse a linked list in java asks about the same algorithm in Java (with different variable names). Have a look and see if those answers help you with understanding the algorithm.

1-->2--->3--->4
first = 1-->
second = 2-->3-->
In while
1º)
temp = 3-->4
second.next = 1-->2-->
first = 2-->1-->
second = 3-->
2º)
temp = 4
second.next=2-->1-->
first = 3-->2-->1-->
second = 4
3º)
temp = null
second.next = 3-->2-->1-->
first = 4-->3-->
second = null
4º)Out while
next 1 = null
head = 4-->3-->2-->1

A linkedList is basically sequential nodes with pointers to the next one in the list. The while loop in there is essentially taking that pointer and pointing it to the previous one instead of the next one which is why we have to hold a reference to the "temp" node.
The loop holds a reference to 3 sequential nodes at a time and it is "flipping" the pointer to second one only.
// before the first loop:  
// it sets first to the head  
// it sets first to the tail  
// it sets second to the node that first is pointing to  

[first = node1] ---> [second = node2] --->   

// in the loop:  
// it only holds reference to what is inside the ( )  
([first = node1] ---> [second = node2] --->) [node3] ---> 

// add reference to the third node so we don't lose it 
const temp = second.next;  
([first = node1] ---> [second = node2] ---> [temp = node3] --->) [node4] --->  

// set the reference of the second node to the first instead of third  
second.next = first;  
([first = node1] **<--->** [second = node2] <-*no more pointer here*-> [temp = node3] --->) [node4] ---> 
 
// shift the nodes  
first = second; 
[first = node2] <---> [second = node2] <-*no more pointer here*-> [temp = node3] --->)   [node4] ---> 


// shift the nodes  
second = temp;    
[first = node2] <---> [second = node3] <-*no more pointer here*-> [temp = node3] --->)   [node4] ---> 

// Sooo, after the first loop:  
[node1] <--->( [first = node2]     [second = node3] ) ---> [node4] --->  

// We have changed the direction of the pointer of the second node to  
// point at the first node instead of the third. Because we have removed 
// that pointer, if we hadn't saved the third node in "temp" we would have 
// lost a reference to the rest of list.

// for the next loop:  
[node1] <---> ( [first = node2]     [second = node3] ) ---> [temp = node4] --->

// after sequential loops:  
[node(n)] <--- ([node(n+1)]   [node(n+2)]) ---> [node(n+3)] ---> 

// after the loop:  
[node1] <---> [node2] <--- [node3] <--- [node4]

// Finally, It sets the old heads pointer to null:  
this.head.next = null;  
[node1] **<---** [node2] <--- [node3] <--- [node4]

// Then sets the new head to the last node we have a reference to, which 
// is first (previously the tail)  
this.head = first;

